# How to encrypt XOR hex string 32 in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, encode

I'm trying to encrypt some of my passwords using the XOR encryption algorithm. I tested it on CyberChef but I don't know how to convert it from PHP. I look forward to helping. Thanks a lot.
[XOR HEX string 32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X54WH.jpg)

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use password_hash?

Comment: I want to learn more. thank.

Comment: You shouldn't encrypt passwords. They should be hashed.

Comment: Besides the password, I want to learn it so that I can serve many other jobs. I want to learn it. if possible please help me don't ask me more about why i don't use other coding....i want to learn. please.

Comment: What do you want to learn exactly? What's the specific part you have trouble with?

Comment: i want to process "my test string" in PHP so that it get the output like the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X54WH.jpg

Comment: Do you even know what a XOR is?

Comment: No, actually I don't know. please instruct me. thank.

Comment: Enter XOR in Google; click on the Wikipedia link; read the page.

Comment: so it won't work with PHP?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting learning exercise, but if that's really what you want, then you've got to go out and do some learning. Right now, there isn't really a question here, just a vague request for us to do all your research for you. Find out what "xor" means, look for ways of doing it in PHP, and then come back here if you have a *specific* question, as discussed at [ask].

Comment: I have consulted and tried using a few available sources: https://github.com/sathoro/php-xor-cipher but I don't understand what HEX key 32 is and how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you ask a bunch of professional programmers how to "encrypt a password" you raise a lot of red flags. We pros spend a lot of time trying to slow down cybercriminals. Encrypted passwords, especially with trivial-to-crack ciphers like XOR, do not slow down cybercriminals. Not even a little bit. That's why you catch so much flak from us. [XOR Ciphers are written up here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher). They depend on [secure key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) to protect data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to start with the basic data structures involved.

**Your objective** is to use a secret *key* to transform your *plain text* -- the message you wish to keep secret -- into *encrypted text*. By definition your plain text is easy for an adversary to understand, and your encrypted text is not.

Then, the rest of your objective is to use the key to transform the encrypted text back into plain text. XOR is a symmetric cipher: it uses exactly the same key to encrypt and to decrypt.

**Basic data structures**

You have *text strings* like `ATTACK` for example.

You have *arrays* like

```
array( 65, 84, 84, 65, 67, 75)
```

And you have [base 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) [encoded](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) strings like

```
base64_encode( "ATTACK" ); //QVRUQUNL
```

**Your data structures**

Let's say your message is ATTACK. (This kind of crypto started with military applications, of course.)  That's an array of numbers. [Your php example](https://github.com/sathoro/php-xor-cipher/blob/d00856ca099722e85e414f4f239400c5be425c88/XORCipher.php#L47) converts your message into an array of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character values.  This [little bit of code](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=s7EvyCjg5eLlUinISczMK0mtKFGwVVB3DAlxdPZWt4aJhwDFHYuTMzOBktGx1iANaflFqYnJGQoaxSVF8cUFOZklGggzNBUSixVUclJLSlKLNBWqebkUgAAhDTYqOhZoWH5RigZMHdDYWpDJBUVAVfFFChpoGjStAQ%2C%2C) does that. It uses the [ord()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) function to convert a letter into a number, called a codepoint. Run it.

```php
$plaintext = 'ATTACK';
$plaintextASCII = [];
foreach( str_split( $plaintext ) as $letter) {
  $plaintextAscii[] = ord( $letter );
}
print_r( $plaintextAscii );
```

It does the same thing as this line of code from your example, but using an explicit loop rather than the `array_map()` shortcut.

```
return array_map('ord', str_split($text));
```

Then you can mangle that array of character values. The XOR cipher is a way to do that.

Finally you convert it back to a string using the [chr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) function.

```
$encryptedString = '';
foreach ( $plaintextAscii as $codepoint ) {
  $encryptedString .= chr( $codepoint );
}
```

But, because you mangled your codepoints to encrypt them, this `$encryptedString` contains non-printable characters. So you cannot just paste the string into an email or something like that.  Instead, you must encode the string using only printable characters.

```
base64_encode( $encryptedString );
```

That's the encrypted message.  To decrypt it you reverse the process.

That should get you started understanding this example code.

**Pro tip** when trying to understand an algorithm, don't try to *use* open-source packages. Instead, look at their code and copy the interesting lines into your own sample code.

**Pro tip** get a decent debugger program so you can step through your code.

**Online security tip** do not, repeat not, use this kind of encryption to store peoples' passwords online. It's not secure enough to slow down cybercreeps. php has a really good set of password-hashing functions. [Read about them here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Comment: Some may say this question didn't deserve an answer. But people new to our trade sometimes need a nudge or two in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your support. i understood the whole problem and also solved my problem. thank you very much.